clerk sign-in functionality in next.js un-styled after refresh in production mode
i currently using clerk with nextjs in my project. i follow their documentation, starting with ClerkProvider etc... then i found some bug, when i visit /sign-in page in working perfectly fine, but when i refresh the page, then i got un-styled sign-in page.

this is my layout.tsx in /src/app

import "@/css/globals.css";
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { fajllaOne, lobster, poppins, ubuntu, bebasNeue } from '@/lib/fonts'
import { ClerkProvider } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { dark } from "@clerk/themes";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Title",
  description: "simple descriptioin",
};

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {

  return (
    <ClerkProvider appearance={{
      baseTheme: dark
    }} >
      <html
        lang="en"
        className={`scroll-smooth ${fajllaOne.variable} ${lobster.variable} ${poppins.variable} ${ubuntu.variable} ${bebasNeue.variable}`}
      >
        <body>
          {children}
        </body>
      </html>
    </ClerkProvider>
  );
}


and this is my sign-in page in /src/app/sign-in/[[...sign-in]]/page.tsx


import { SignIn } from '@clerk/nextjs'

export default function SignInPage() {
    return (
        <div className="min-h-screen flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
            <SignIn
                fallbackRedirectUrl={'/home'}
                appearance={{
                    elements: {
                        rootBox: 'flex justify-center items-center my-5 rounded-md shadow-lg overflow-hidden shadow-blue-800',
                        cardBox: 'bg-gray-800',
                        input: 'bg-transparent bg-none',
                    }
                }}
            />
        </div>

    )
}

and also after user sign-in in first time, that sign-in button doesn't redirect back to my site (in this case localhost:3000), but stay in clerk site (i think)
i tried to re-position the  on root layout. first like this
export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {

  return (
    <html
      lang="en"
      className={`scroll-smooth ${fajllaOne.variable} ${lobster.variable} ${poppins.variable} ${ubuntu.variable} ${bebasNeue.variable}`}
    >
      <ClerkProvider appearance={{
        baseTheme: dark
      }} >
        <body>
          {children}
        </body>
      </ClerkProvider>
    </html>
  );
}

and then i move the ClerkProvider to the top of element. and still doesn't work
this is sign-in page looks like when development mode, and its working totally fine in this case
sign-in page
and this is sign-in page in production mode, before i refresh the page its normal but when i refresh the page its look terrible
after refresh sign-in page
